# python - write non-ascii characters to file

Tags: utf-8, python-2.x

I am on Linux and a want to write string (in utf-8) to txt file. This is my code:

```
# -*- coding: UTF-8-*-

import os
import sys


def __init__(self, dirname, speaker, file, exportFile):

      text_file = open(exportFile, "a")

      text_file.write(speaker.encode("utf-8"))
      text_file.write(file.encode("utf-8"))

      text_file.close()
```

When I am on Windows, it works. But on Linux, I get this error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position in position 36: ordinal not in range(128)
```

How can I solve this problem? Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to `decode('utf-8')` to convert your utf8 string to a bytestring?

Comment: do you have a sample or a link to your source?

Comment: Have you tried opening the file in `"au"` mode?

Comment: Yes, I tried "au" mode. I got the same error.

Comment: Can you try to use mode `"ab"` (binary mode), which is described in documentation to avoid text mode?

Answer (score 9):

You could try to use the "codecs" module:

```
import codecs

with codecs.open('filename', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as out:  
    out.write(u'some text')
```

Comment: With Python 2 it could help to use "u strings"